# Java: geting return value from other class

Tags: java, class, return

i just want to get the value entered in my txtfield from other class

```
public class MyCostumizedDialog{
int x = 0 ;

public void showFrameDialog(){
   // Here are my components...
    txt1 = new Jtextfields;...//my jtxtfield
    .......
    btn1.addactionlister(....){
         x = Integer.parseInt(txt1.gettext());//get string from jtxtfld and parse to int
   }
public int getNumber(){
    return x;
}

}
```

then i want to get the value entered from jtxtfild from MyCostumizedDialog like this

```
public class OtherClass{

    public void frame(){

btn2.addactionlistener(......){
      MyCostumizedDialog mcd = new MyCostumizedDialog();
      mcd .showFrameDialog();
      Double x= mcd.getNumber();
      txtNumber.setText("P "+x);
     }
    }
}
```

txtnumber always show the initial value of x from MycostumeDialog,please help me

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post - it's unreadable at the moment. Read the help for the editor for coding; you don't need the backticks if you're indenting a whole block of code.

Comment: sorry this is my first time, i very sorry,i am just hoping that theres some one who will help me :D

Comment: What triggers the second dialog to update when you check the value in the first?  Are you expecting this to happen automagically?

Comment: yeah, i though it will return the new value of x after pressing the btn1 in MyCostumizedDialog

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to get value before setting value to it in other words your x gets value once you click on btn1, but you are trying to get value of x before clicking on that button.

```
mcd .showFrameDialog();
Double x= mcd.getNumber();
```

you should call `mcd.getNumber();` after you set value to your variable.

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` should help

Comment: it shows the initial value of x again from MyCostumizedDialog,

Comment: what you expect to get? you are creating new object so you will get initial value of x.
instead of 
  Double x= mcd.getNumber();
call
  Double x = Integer.parseInt(mcd.txt1.gettext()); 

and you will have the value of x that is entered in your dialog text input.
don't forget to make txt1 member variable, not local

Comment: if i do that, it parsed it before entering the text,then it has an erre "empty string"

Answer (score 0):

Since you always instantiate a new instance of MyCostumizedDialog every time btn2 is pressed you get the initial value of MyCostumizedDialog because nobody pressed the btn1 for the newly created instance that would set the value.

If the btn1 needs to be there for other purposes I would recommend to just add another method to do exactly the same thing as the btn1 action listener does, and then call that method inside the btn2 action listener.

Comment: what should i do? i want to press btn2 in OtherClass then MyCostumizedDialog will pop.Then user will enter new data in  txt1 then it will close after presing btn1.i thought it will automatically return the new value of x in my OtherClass

Comment: Since I assume that you need to get the value of X to the OtherClass and MyCostumizedDialog is only a means to do that, you could declare X in OtherClass instead of MyCostumizedDialog and then just call a setter method from MyCostumizedDialog when btn1 is pressed that will set the declared X value of the OtherClass

Comment: Ceiling,i just want to use MyCostumizedDialog in many classes,so i just want it the way like JFileChooser Style,well tnx u so much for the knowledge

Comment: A workaround for this might be to stall the execution of btn2 listener until it receives a value that is not "0" or a certain amount of time has passed. You could do this by saving a time snapshot before you execute `Double x= mcd.getNumber();` and then just do a `while((Double x= mcd.getNumber()) != 0)` loop and inside that loop you could compare the current time to the time snapshot you saved before the loop and if the loop runs for a long time like 60 seconds or something then you just call `break;` to not get stuck in an endless loop if something bad happens.